# Two coroutines running simultaneously using asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a program that reads in data as well as sends and receives data from a server through a websocket. The goal is to create synchronized lamps where there are two client lamps and one server. When one of the lamps changes state it sends a request to the server and the server updates the other lamp. I'm currently stuck on the client code. I can establish a websocket connection to the server, read and send data to the server, and I can read in light data. I'm having an issue running both of these tasks simultaneously. I'd like to do it asynchronously to avoid race condition issues. I'm using python 3.8 and asyncio.

Here is my websocket client code so far:

```
async def init_connection(message):
  global CONNECTION_OPEN
  global CLIENT_WS
  uri = WS_URI
  async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
      CONNECTION_OPEN = True
      CLIENT_WS = websocket
      # send init message
      await websocket.send(message)
      while CONNECTION_OPEN:
          await handleMessages(websocket, message)
      await websocket.send(json.dumps({'type': MessageType.Close.name, 'message': USERNAME}))
      await websocket.close()
```

Here is my read in data code so far:

```
async def calculate_idle(t):
  global STATE
  global prevColor
  x_arr = []
  y_arr = []
  z_arr = []
  while t >= 0:
     x, y, z = lis3dh.acceleration
     print("Current colors")
     print(accel_to_color(x,y,z))
     x_arr.append(x)
     y_arr.append(y)
     z_arr.append(z)
     newColor = accel_to_color(x,y,z)
     # remember prev color
     do_fade(prevColor, newColor)
     #strip.fill((int(a_x), int(a_y), int(a_z), 0))
     #strip.show()
     prevColor = newColor
     time.sleep(.2)
     t -= .2
  is_idle = is_lamp_idle(np.std(x_arr), np.std(y_arr), np.std(z_arr))

  if is_idle and STATE == "NOT IDLE" and CONNECTION_OPEN:
      STATE = "IDLE"
      print("Sending color")
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
  elif is_idle and CONNECTION_OPEN:
      # Check for data
      STATE = "IDLE"
      print ("Receiving data")
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
  elif is_idle and not CONNECTION_OPEN:
     print ("Idle and not connected")
      rainbow_cycle(0.001)    # rainbow cycle with 1ms delay per step
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
  else:
      STATE = "NOT IDLE"
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      print("Is not idle")
```

Here is the code that is supposed to tie them together:

```
async def main():
    message = json.dumps({'type': "authentication", 'payload': {
                            'username': 'user1', 'secret': SHARED_SECRET}})
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    start_light = asyncio.create_task(calculate_idle(3))
    await asyncio.gather(init_connection(message), start_light)
asyncio.run(main())
```

There's other functions, but the premise is there's a websocket connection sending and receiving data and another process reading in light data. I also need to be able to read the current state of the lights and set the current state of the lights which is why I was using global variables. Currently, it'll read the lights until it hits an await asyncio.sleep(1) in calculate idle, then switch to the websocket code and hang receiving data from the server. Ideally, it would alternate between reading the current state and checking for websocket messages. If the state changes, it would then send a websocket message.

How can I run both of these routine asynchronously and share the data between them? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By "hang receiving data from the server", do you mean that the `init_connection` coroutine hangs, or that the whole program hangs?

Comment: I think init_connection is blocking the light code from running since I no longer see any light data once that gets hit.

Comment: Can you add a third coroutine with a simple heart-beat, consisting just of `while True: print("tic-toc"); await asyncio.sleep(1)`? Does that one also stop printing?

Comment: Interestingly adding the third coroutine prints while it receives data. It must be an issue with my lights data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s comments to help narrow down the issue. My calculate idle didn't have a while true and I changed time.sleep(.2) to await asyncio.sleep(.2) and I was able to read data from the server and the lights at the same time.